# "Failed to start apparmor initialization" after updating

Tags: server, 18.04, updates

I am running Ubuntu server 18.04. I just updated everything. After I restarted it says Failed to start apparmor initialization. When I try to start it manually it fails again and tells me to run systemctl status apparmor.service. When I run that this is the result:

```
    ● apparmor.service - AppArmor initialization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-04-07 06:48:34 UTC; 3min 10s ago
     Docs: man:apparmor(7)
           http://wiki.apparmor.net/
  Process: 2913 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apparmor start (code=exited, status=123)
 Main PID: 2913 (code=exited, status=123)

Apr 07 06:48:34 webserver apparmor[2913]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Apr 07 06:48:34 webserver apparmor[2913]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real at line 11: Could not
Apr 07 06:48:34 webserver apparmor[2913]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Apr 07 06:48:34 webserver apparmor[2913]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real at line 11: Could not
Apr 07 06:48:34 webserver apparmor[2913]: AppArmor parser error for /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine.core.6130 in /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine.core.6130 at lin
Apr 07 06:48:34 webserver apparmor[2913]: AppArmor parser error for /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine.core.6130 in /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine.core.6130 at lin
Apr 07 06:48:34 webserver apparmor[2913]:    ...fail!
Apr 07 06:48:34 webserver systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=123/n/a
Apr 07 06:48:34 webserver systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 07 06:48:34 webserver systemd[1]: Failed to start AppArmor initialization.
```

How should I fix this? Should I even worry about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install snapd

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

Don't know why that didn't happen automatically

Comment: What a simple solution. It worked !